# Proof that $L^p$-space is $p\wedge2$-uniformly smooth

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am having a look at the chapter "Uniform Convexity and Uniform Smoothness" from the book "Geometry and Martingales in Banach Spaces" by Woyczynski.

I would like to prove Example 3.1.2: For $p>1$, the $L^p$-space is $p\wedge 2$-uniformly smooth when equipped with the $L^p$-norm.

I think that I have found a proof, but I am not quite sure where I used the fact that $p$ may not be bigger than 2. What I have gathered is the follwoing: Let $f,g\in L^p$. Then we have: $$||(f+g)/2||+ ||(f-g)/2||-1
= \frac{1}{2}  \left( \int |f(x)+g(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p} +\frac{1}{2}  \left( \int |f(x)-g(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p} -1 \\
    \overset{(1)}{\leq} \left( \int \frac{1}{2}|f(x)+g(x)|^p + \frac{1}{2}|f(x)-g(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p} -1 \\
    \overset{(2)}{\leq}  \left( \int |f(x)|^p +|g(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p} -1 \\
    = \left( ||f||^p+||g||^p \right)^{1/p} -1\\
    =  (1+\tau^p)^{1/p} -1 \\
\leq \tau^p $$
where (1) uses that the $p$-th root is concave and (2) is just the fact that $|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p\leq |a|^p + |b|^p.$

I think my problem is less about uniform smoothness and more about the calculations that are done here. I suspect $|a+b|^p+|a-b|^p\leq |a|^p + |b|^p$ to hold, but find myself unable to prove this or find a source. Also, I cannot imagine how this would only hold for $p>2$.

I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: Pick $a=b=1$, then your inequality gives $2^p\leq 2$, and so $p\leq 1$.